# Trying to use Ruby super to call method directly

Tags: ruby

Consider this code:

```
class Hello
  def hi
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

class HelloWorld < Hello
  def hi
    super.hi
    puts "World"
  end
end

HelloWorld.new.hi
```

Gives output:

```
$ ruby super.rb
Hello
super.rb:9:in `hi': undefined method `hi' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from super.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

Why does Hello get printed? I would expect to just get the error. Also I know that what I really should be doing is just calling `super` instead of `super.hi` but I want to understand what is happening "under the hood".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`super` already automatically calls the method that is being overridden. What's happening is that `hi` in `Hello` returns `nil`, because it simply did `puts` which returns `nil` (and it's the last expression). So Ruby evaluates `super`, which calls the method, and then it tries to access the `hi` method from the resulting `nil` object, and there is none.

Comment: Thanks! That makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

**`super.hi`** is only the method chaining you put inside the class `HelloWorld`.The call to `super` is valid,but on return value from *super call*,is `nil` due to `puts` statement.And then `nil.hi` is the culprit.

```
class Hello
  def hi
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

class HelloWorld < Hello
  def hi
    super.hi
    puts "World"
  end
end

HelloWorld.new.hi
# ~> -:9:in `hi': undefined method `hi' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is because `super` method is called first,which produces the output `Hello`,by calling `Hello#hi`. Now `puts "Hello"` made the `super` method to return `nil`. `NilClass` don't have the `hi` method,thus `nil.hi` throws error. See now the same thing with different taste.

```
class Hello
  def hi
    p "Hello"
  end
end

class HelloWorld < Hello
  def hi
    super.hi
    puts "World"
  end
end

HelloWorld.new.hi
# ~> -:9:in `hi': undefined method `hi' for "Hello":String (NoMethodError)
# ~>  from -:14:in `<main>'
# >> "Hello"
```

Here I changed the `puts` to `p`,so now as per the convention `p "Hello"` returns the `"Hello"` String itself,unlike `puts`.But the error is definite,as `String` class don't have the method `hi`,so the now `"Hello".hi` throws the legitimate error.